# Need permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN for android > 12

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm having a problem with my application.

I'm defined all permissions in manifest, and try give in my checkPermission(), but, don't learning BLUETOOTH_SCAN... but, in android's with SKD 30 < its works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide some code details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask